# Cannot find module 'jws'

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

When pushing my app to Bluemix with no local node_modules and adding the `passport-idaas-openidconnect` dependency I get the following errors, it says the issue is with my app and not npm, but the error is from `/home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport-idaas-openidconnect/lib/strategy.js:8:11`

```
ERR module.js:338
ERR;
ERR           ^
ERRor: Cannot find module 'jws'
ERR     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
ERR     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
ERR     at require (module.js:384:17)
ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport-idaas-openidconnect/lib/strategy.js:8:11)
ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
ERR     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
ERR     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
ERR     at require (module.js:384:17)
ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
ERR! node v0.12.10
ERR! npm  v2.14.9
ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
ERR! myapp@0.4.2 start: `node app.js`
ERR! Exit status 1
ERR!
ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.4.2 start script 'node app.js'.
ERR! This is most likely a problem with the myapp package,
ERR! not with npm itself.
ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
ERR!     node app.js
ERR! You can get their info via:
ERR!     npm owner ls myappe
ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
```

Comment: Can you post the context of '(/home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport-idaas-openidconnect/lib/strategy.js:8:11'

Comment: Could you please post here you package.json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to push a Node.js application with SSO capabilities using Bluemix SSO service, you'll need at least the following dependencies in your package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    [...]
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "passport": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-idaas-openidconnect": "^1.0.0"
    [...]
  }
```

Please note that the passport-idaas-openidconnect module works with passport versions 0.1.1 up to 0.3.2. Versions later than 0.3.2 might not work correctly, as reported in [Bluemix Single Sign On Docs - Configuring apps](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/configure_apps.html#tsk_configuringnodejsapp_express4).

Comment: Thanks I forgot to include the ^ in my "passport" version.